# How can we create new tags?

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation-process

I want to add a tag that is not present yet as a tag. Who adds tags, can we add tags? If yes, then how can we?

Comment: What tag do you want to create and what question(s)?

Answer (score 3):

If the tag exists, you can add it by editing a post.

If it does not exist, you can create it - *if* you have enough points. The [privilege to create tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) unlocks at 1500 points.

If you believe a tag is needed, but isn't present, and you don't have enough points to create it - then you can suggest to create it on Meta, like you did here. Then we can discuss if the tag is indeed necessary, and if so, create it.

Note that we don't create tags for the sake of creating them. You need an actual question where the tag would be useful.

Comment: I would've write request for tag in comments to question prior to meta discussion.